# How can i schedule the automated workflow in Mac

Tags: macos, automator

I have tried to change the IP of a server via script and schedule it automatically but it was not giving proper results.So i relied on a tacky method of doing it using "Automator"app in Mac.

I created a workflow using this Automator ,Now i need to schedule this to work every 10 minutes or so.How can i do that in Mac with any scripts or anything. Suggestions will be o great help.

[image: mat]

Below is the workflow created.

Comment: This article might be useful to you: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html

Comment: @osoclever This is cron right? I have a workflow saved, How i can use cron to do that, Sorry im new to this.If you can show an example will be great.